# Loop takes so much time to run

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to make the below code more efficient.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    current_row = df.iloc[i]    
    if i > 0:
        previous_row =df.iloc[i-1]
    else:
        previous_row = current_row 
    if (current_row['A'] != 1):
        if ((current_row['C'] < 55) and (current_row['D'] >= -1)):
            df.loc[i,'F'] = previous_row['F'] + 1
        else: 
            df.loc[i,'F'] = previous_row['F']
```

For example if the dataframe is like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'C':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'D':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
'F':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
```

My output should look like this

```
>>> df
   A  C  D  F
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  2
4  0  0  0  3
5  0  0  0  4
6  1  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  2
8  0  1  1  3
```

Comment: `previous_row` should be `prev_row`?

Comment: I'm not a pandas programmer, but it seems like you should be able to do it with built-in filtering rather than a loop.

Comment: Can you describe what the code should do? In Pandas you shouldn't have to write many, if any, loops.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Can you actually describe in words what you're trying to achieve? The example you gave doesn't help understand the problem domain (if C only contains 1 or 0, why are you checking `< 55`?)

Comment: So basically, if the conditions are met, I want the value of 'F' to be modified as the previous row of 'F' +1. (if C only contains 1 or 0, why are you checking < 55?), It was just an example, 'C' might have values != (0,1)